# unable to access windows partition after deleting partition

Tags: windows, grub

Here my situation, I have a dual boot one partition with windows 10 and another one with Ubuntu.

I just delete the ubuntu partition in disk manager in windows. 
But then when I try to reboot, I get a grub rescue screen.

What could I try to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going from memory:

If you have the installation media for Windows 10, pop it in and boot off of it.

**DO NOT SELECT NEW INSTALL**

There should be an option for Recovery Console or Repair or something similar.

if you can get to a console, the command to fix the mbr is

```
bootsect /nt60 C: /mbr
```

This assumes that the OS was installed on the C Drive